# I can just boot my system from grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I had a problem after the Ubuntu installation because after the restart the system wont boot. In live mode I found a helpful tip, how I can boot into my installed version of Ubuntu. I can just boot from grump of the live disk with the following:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Because I am totally new to Linux I want to know how I can get my computer to boot automatically like this because I do not want to boot it manually every time I start it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boot-Repair while you're live on usb .

installation :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it will automatically repair your grub .

Source:

[Ofiicial Ubuntu Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)